# How to display msbuild errors on the overview page from TeamCity

Tags: powershell, psake, teamcity-7.1

I want to use PowerShell with Psake and TeamCity to configure my CI. I used to standard Msbuild runner but now I wrote my own script for building solution but I have problem when msbuild failed.

When I was using Msbuild runner and build failed then on Overview page new section “Build errors” appears and I have there detail from msbuild. But when I wrote my custom scripts I got only error “Process exited with code 1” and I don’t know how to “create” this build errors section. Do you know how to do this? I know that I can use [service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) but I can't handle failed log from msbuild.

```
task compile {
try {
   exec { msbuild $code_dir\SampleSolution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release }
} catch {
   Write-Host $_ #only information that error occured, but without any msbui details
} }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the build log file?

Comment: Msbuild build log - yes

Comment: Here is quite good solution: [link](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/EnterpriseDev/application-lifecycle-management/displaying-net-build-warnings-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify [log for MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Parse error from log or attach whole log as build artifact.

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts '.\msbuild.log']
```

To fail build you can use the following message

```
Write-Output "##teamcity[message text='MS Build failed' status='ERROR']"
```

You can get all messages that can be used [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages)